# Setting up webhooks (to my Server) called by special keywords from Google Speaker

Tags: iot, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

Its possible?
As I know it was possible by Conversational Actions, but its now deprecated.
More detail about my case:

*Some user will request help of manager through Google Speaker. And need logging this information in my server, I think with some webhook from Google`s server.*

Or it might be realised by Google Speaker/Google Nest Hub/Nest Mini in other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the conversational action being deprecated this is not possible anymore. Here is the conversational action deprecation [page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset).